# How to deploy 2 war files to one instance of Tomcat7 on different ports?

Tags: java, netbeans, tomcat7

In Netbeans, is it possible to deploy two different war files to two different ports in one tomcat instance ?

I know I can do this manually by copying and pasting individual war files to their respective appBase folders or by using a copy-maven-plugin. But is this possible in Netbeans ?

Here is my server.xml file configuration

```
<Service name="App1">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
        </Realm>
        <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps8080" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"/>
    </Engine>
</Service>
<Service name="App2">
    <Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8444" />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
        </Realm>
        <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps8081" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"/>
    </Engine>
</Service>
```

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366843/how-to-deploy-mutiple-web-application-in-tomcat-which-will-run-on-different-port

Comment: My question is Netbeans related. The above configuration works well with Tomcat on it's own.