# Configure eureka server port

Tags: java, tomcat8, netflix-eureka

I have the following:
1. Tomcat server running @port 9080
2. eureka.war (1.6.2-SNAPSHOT) deployed in the tomcat

Is there a way that I can configure the eureka-client (fired by eureka-server itself) to be exposed at a different port (say:- 7001) than Tomcat Http Connector port (here 9080)?

Any such customization for `eureka.port` throws the following error repeatedly; which in a normal startup with same port as tomcat server port; goes away after 1st occurence:

```
2017-01-19 18:06:36,096 WARN  com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient:129 [DiscoveryClient-CacheRefreshExecutor-0] [execute] Request execution failed with message: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
2017-01-19 18:06:36,097 ERROR com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient:934 [DiscoveryClient-CacheRefreshExecutor-0] [fetchRegistry] DiscoveryClient_EUREKA/instanceID - was unable to refresh its cache! status = Cannot execute request on any known server
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:111)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1013)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:927)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1451)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$CacheRefreshThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1418)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2017-01-19 18:06:36,145 ERROR com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient:83 [DiscoveryClient-HeartbeatExecutor-0] [execute] Request execution error
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123)
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.put(WebResource.java:529)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.sendHeartBeat(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:102)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:119)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.renew(DiscoveryClient.java:815)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1379)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:120)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:179)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:612)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:447)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:117)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173)
    ... 27 more
2017-01-19 18:06:36,148 WARN  com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient:129 [DiscoveryClient-HeartbeatExecutor-0] [execute] Request execution failed with message: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
2017-01-19 18:06:36,148 ERROR com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient:824 [DiscoveryClient-HeartbeatExecutor-0] [renew] DiscoveryClient_EUREKA/instanceID- was unable to send heartbeat!
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:111)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.renew(DiscoveryClient.java:815)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1379)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: if you use spring boot cloud which based on netflix microservice infrastructure, that would be easy. i suggested you do it if you are just starting your project

Comment: Well it's a conscious effort to see if eureka can be used in a spring boot or any java application wo using spring cloud. Except for port customization I've followed the netflix eureka wiki (https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Configuring-Eureka) otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be possible with same instance ([see here](https://coderanch.com/t/501855/java/deploy-war-port)) or without some Custom Connector [setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366843/how-to-deploy-mutiple-web-application-in-tomcat-which-will-run-on-different-port) . `eureka` deployed in tomcat (*here*) is a war and it makes sense to be exposed at the same Server connector port, where it is deployed. `eureka-client` is a jar which is a part of `eureka.war` probably can't listen to anywhere else.